# Joining two tables on MySQL with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm pretty new to MySQL and I'm struggling with this problem. I have two different tables (T1 and T2) and T2's got all elements from T1, with some extra ones.

I'm trying to get the variable "company" from T2 for all values from T1, such as:

```
SELECT
T2.company as company,
T1.route as route,
T1.departure_time,
T1.arrival_time
```

when some conditions are satisfied, such as:

```
T1.route LIKE(CONCAT(T2.airport1,T2.airport2)) AND
T1.departure_time = T2.departure_time AND
T1.arrival_time = T2.arrival_time
```

How can I do this? Sorry for the basic question, but i'm really desperate right now about this. Thank you so much.

OBS: yeah, the bad part is that the two tables came from different sources and there are no unique key values to join them accordingly, so that's why I'm struggling with all those conditions...

Comment: What are the keys on the tables ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT
  T2.company as company,
  T1.route as route,
  T1.departure_time,
  T1.arrival_time
from
  t1,t2
where
  T1.route LIKE(CONCAT(T2.airport1,T2.airport2)) AND
  T1.departure_time = T2.departure_time AND
  T1.arrival_time = T2.arrival_time
```

Comment: yeah I tried that as well, but it was also taking so long that I was receiving server time outs... the two tables are huge, with 8,5 million entries each

Comment: It seems that the structure is flawed a bit. You should reorganize the tables a bit. Add them proper primary keys/foreign keys and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions in the ON clause, like so

```
SELECT Fields
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.company=T2.company 
AND T1.route LIKE(CONCAT(T2.airport1,T1.airport2)) 
AND T1.departure_time = T2.departure_time
AND T1.arrival_time = T2.arrival_time
```

that is, for the conditions that just serve the purpose of being sure that the rows really are connected, conditions to determine which line to be selected would go after the WHERE clause. consider the following line to go immediately after the other ones

```
WHERE T1.company='airFoo'
```

Comment: I actually tried using LEFT JOIN for that just like you suggested, but it took so long that I got a timeout response, so I concluded that I must have been doing something wrong...

Comment: can you post the actual query used? also be sure to correctly index the fields used. if you have large tables this can really slow down queries